# Can my android application be launched from built-in Phone Call Log application?

Tags: android

I would like to know if it is possible to launch my application whenever a new entry is written to phone call log (i.e. out-going, in-coming or missed call).

I wrote an application to manage the call log entries as per user preferences by listening to the publication of **android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE** events. My application is working fine as long as its process is running. However if the user has stopped my application with a task-killer application, then the log entries can not be managed as my app itself was not running. I need a way to make sure that my application is launched in the background if it is not already running when the **android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE** occurs.

Or is it possible to launch my application as a service that always runs?

Thanks in advance.
Bala

Answer (score 2):

You can launch your application as Service:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

here is a basic service implementation:

```
public class MyService extends Service
{
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i("Service", "Service is starting");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i("Service", "Service stopped");
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application ....>
    <service android:name=".App.MySyncService" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

> However if the user has stopped my
>   application with a task-killer
>   application, then the log entries can
>   not be managed as my app itself was
>   not running.

There is nothing that can be done about this. The same thing will occur if the user terminates your service through the Settings > Applications page.

> I need a way to make sure that my
>   application is launched in the
>   background if it is not already
>   running when the
>   android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE
>   occurs.

You can try setting up a `BroadcastReceiver` for this Intent in your manifest, and have it route control over to some `IntentService` for processing. It's the same pattern I use for `AlarmManager` ([sample code here](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SystemServices/Alarm/)), just with a different trigger. I have not tried this specific `Intent`, though, so I cannot be certain the technique works. If it does, though, it has a huge benefit of keeping your service out of memory most of the time (`IntentService` shuts down when its work is complete), which will make your task-killing users happy.

> Or is it possible to launch my
>   application as a service that always
>   runs?

No, because users are in control over their devices, not you or I.